# using tensorflow functions with tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a question regarding tf.keras and tf functions in tf 2.0.
If i have a model like this:

```
 inputdata = keras.Input(shape=(2048, 1))
    x = layers.Conv1D(16, 3, activation='relu')(inputdata)
    x = layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu')(x)
```

and I want to add a custom function like this which is a 1D SubPixel Layer:

```
def SubPixel1D(I, r):
  with tf.name_scope('subpixel'):
  X = tf.transpose(I, [2,1,0]) # (r, w, b)
  X = tf.batch_to_space_nd(X, [r], [[0,0]]) # (1, r*w, b)
  X = tf.transpose(X, [2,1,0])
  return X
```

can I include this layer in keras without problems? Since tensorflow 2.0 is so much easier then the previous tensorflow versions iam not sure about it if this is not mixing up the backends and the sessions?

```
inputdata = keras.Input(shape=(2048, 1))
  x = layers.Conv1D(16, 3, activation='relu')(inputdata)
  x = layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu')(x)
  x = SubPixel1D(x,2)
  x = layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu')(x)
```

after that compile and fit model will work? If
tensorflow and keras is imported

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 from tensorflow import keras
```

similar to the a custom loss function in keras.
If I define a custom loss function like this:

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
 # compute l2 loss/ equal to Keras squared mean
    sqrt_l2_loss = tf.reduce_mean((y_pred-y_true)**2, axis=[1, 2])
    avg_sqrt_l2_loss = tf.reduce_mean(sqrt_l2_loss, axis=0)
    return avg_sqrt_l2_loss
```

and use tf. operations or functions, can i just pass this function to keras as usual?
Can i just use it in Keras loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subclass `tf.keras.Layer` and you will be good to go. Great reference here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models. Your layer should look something like this:

```
class SubPixel1D(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, r)
      super(SubPixel1D, self).__init__()
      self.r = r

  def call(self, inputs):
      with tf.name_scope('subpixel'):
          X = tf.transpose(inputs, [2,1,0]) # (r, w, b)
          X = tf.batch_to_space_nd(X, [self.r], [[0,0]]) # (1, r*w, b)
          X = tf.transpose(X, [2,1,0])
     return X
```

and then call it when defining your model

```
inputdata = keras.Input(shape=(2048, 1))
  x = layers.Conv1D(16, 3, activation='relu')(inputdata)
  x = layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu')(x)
  x = SubPixel1D(2)(x)
  x = layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu')(x)
```

I don't know how `tf.name_scope` will behave, but I don't see any immediate issues.

Comment: you have seen my previous question regarding overfitting....  i trained my model without that wrapping. I just used the subpixel function and called it in my model. Do you think it makes a difference? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60461069/how-important-is-the-loss-difference-between-training-and-validation-data-at-the/60470230?noredirect=1#comment107034012_60470230